# Issue with adding Data to an AnyObject Var so that I could make native ads work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob, native-ads

```
 for postdata in postdata {
        if index < tableViewItems.count {
            tableViewItems.insert(postdata, at: index)
            index += adInterval
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
```

I'll need to add both PostData ads and Native Ads on the same AnyObject Var for me to get it to work and I can't find a way to add the Post Data because it says an error appears saying "Argument type 'PostData' expected to be an instance of a class or class-constrained type." Assistance would be very much appreciated, thank you.

edit 1

```
class Ad {
    var postimage: String!
    var publisher: String!
    var timestring: String!
    var timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
}

class PostDataAd: Ad {

    // Declare here your custom properties
    struct PostData1
    {
        var postimage: String
        var publisher: String
        var timestring : String
        var timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    }
}

class NativeAd: Ad {
    // Declare here your custom properties
    struct NativeAd
    {
        var nativeAds: [GADUnifiedNativeAd] = [GADUnifiedNativeAd]()
    }
}
```

My model class to merge both Data into one AnyObject Var

and then trying to append the Data from Firebase by doing this

```
var ads: [Ad] = [PostDataAd(), NativeAd()]

let postList = PostDataAd.PostData1(postimage: postimage, publisher: 
postpublisher, timestring: postid, timestamp: timestamp)

self.ads.insert(postList, at:0)
```

an error occurs saying Cannot convert value of type 'PostDataAd.PostData1' to expected argument type 'Ad'

Comment: What is `PostData`, what is `tableViewItems`? How are they declared?

Comment: PostData is the Data from Firebase and tableViewItems is an AnyObject Array that I'm trying to store My PostData in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got what you want correctly. So basically you have two objects which you want to store in one array, under `AnyObject`. If that is correct, I recommend you to go in a bit of different direction. It is a nice example where you can use subclassing. You can declare a class called `Ad`, where you define the common properties which will be true for both `PostDataAds` and `NativeAds`.

```
class Ad {
    // Add here the common elements you want to retrieve from both classes
    var name: String = ""
}
```

After you define your `PostDataAds` and `NativeAds` inheriting from `Ad`:

```
class PostDataAd: Ad {
    // Declare here your custom properties
}

class NativeAd: Ad {
    // Declare here your custom properties
}
```

And if you want to define an array with two types of objects you can go:

```
let ads: [Ad] = [PostDataAd(), NativeAd()]
```

When retrieving you can check their type:

```
if let item = ads.first as? PostDataAd {
     // The Ad is a PostDataAd
} else if let item = ad as? NativeAd {
    // The Ad is a NativeAd
}
```

Or at some cases you don't even how to know the exact type, as you can access the properties defined in `Ad` without checking.

**Update:**

First of all your `PostData1` and `Ad` objects are the same, you don't need to duplicate them. If you really want to have two classes you can inherit `PostData1` from `Ad`.

```
class Ad {
    var postimage: String
    var publisher: String
    var timestring: String
    var timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

    // You can add timestamp here also if you wish
    init(postimage: String, publisher: String, timestring: String) {
        self.postimage = postimage
        self.publisher = publisher
        self.timestring = timestring
    }
}

class PostDataAd: Ad {
    // Define some custom properties
}
```

And if you want to append `PostData` to the `[Ad]` array, you would do the following:

```
var ads: [Ad] = []
// Replace with your values
let postList = PostDataAd(postimage: "", publisher: "", timestring: "") 
ads.insert(postList, at: 0)

// Appending NativeAd works also
let nativeAdd = NativeAd(postimage: "", publisher: "", timestring: "")
ads.append(nativeAdd)
```

Comment: I'll try this, Thank you for your assistance

Comment: let postList = PostDataAd.PostData(postimage: postimage, publisher: postpublisher, timestring: postid, timestamp: timestamp)   is what I use to store my data from firebase and on trying to append it with self.ads.insert(postList, at:0)        there's an error saying  Cannot convert value of type 'PostDataAd.PostData' to expected argument type 'Ad' any help around this?

Comment: @AbuNabé could you please update your code what you are doing exactly ?

Comment: thank you so much, really appreciate the help